# RShiny: Save the html content of an htmlOutput

Tags: html, r, shiny, rshiny

I develop a shiny app with a manager interface. This interface allows a statistician to import data and create plots. I would like to save the html element to display on the user page by `renderUI({HTML(content)})`. The same question is ask on rstudio community website : https://community.rstudio.com/t/how-can-i-save-r-shiny-html-output-to-an-external-file/89415

For example on the example below how to save the content of `htmlOutput('content')`

[image]

```
library(shiny)
library(datasets)
library(shinyjqui)

# Global variables 
n <- 200

# Define the UI
ui <- fluidPage(
  
  numericInput('n', 'Number of obs', n),
  selectInput("region", "Region:", 
              choices=colnames(WorldPhones)),
  br(),br(),
  
  htmlOutput('content')
)


# Define the server code
server <- function(input, output) {

output$content <- renderUI({
fluidRow(
      jqui_resizable(column(6, plotOutput('plot1'))),
      jqui_resizable(column(6, plotOutput('plot2')))
    )
})
  
output$plot1 <- renderPlot({
    hist(runif(input$n))
  })

output$plot2 <- renderPlot({
barplot(WorldPhones[,input$region]*1000, 
          main=input$region,
          ylab="Number of Telephones",
          xlab="Year")
})

}

shinyApp(ui = ui, server = server)
```

Thank you for your reply

Comment: If you want users to download a dynamically generated HTML file you have to user rmarkdown, knit to HTML and provide a download link in the app (which triggers the knitting of the rmarkdown).

Comment: The goal is not to download in html by user.
But to save the bookmarkings done in the admin page and display the content in the user page. –

I found `jqui_bookmarking()` [](https://yang-tang.github.io/shinyjqui/articles/save-and-restore.html) which allows to do bookmarking state with the functions of **shinyjqui** package . –

idea : save the state of the admin page and get a URL that will restore the application for the user. –

But I notice that it does not take into account the htmlOutput('content') in the UI and  `output$content <- renderUI({ fluidRow( ... )})` in the server.

Comment: Sorry, I'm confused. Don't you just need shiny's [built-int bookmarking feature](https://shiny.rstudio.com/articles/bookmarking-state.html)?

Comment: Sorry I'll try to explain better. –  

Option 1: I want a solution to save id="content" (corresponding to my shiny::htmlOutput) as html. Then use includeHTML in the user page.  –

Option 2: use shiny's Bookmarking to save stage and load after in the user page.  –

option 1, I idn't find solution. And option 2 Bookmarking seems not to take into account the packge shinyjqui and doesn't take into account the `output$content <- renderUI({ fluidRow( ... )})` in the server.